# Unable to Subset in randomForest() function in R

Tags: r, random-forest, training-data

I am trying to use randomForest function in R. For my analysis, I have a dataset that has 151 observations. I used 70/30 split to get 105 observations in training and 46 n test.

I'm using subset argument to indicate training dataset observations. However, when I use the "rf$predicted" command, I see that the model used the entire dataset (151 observations, and not just the training dataset.

Also, when I use the "predict()" function to provide test data, the model is using the predicting on 150 observations. But, the test has only 46 observations.

Can you please tell me what I may be doing wrong? I want to fit the model using the training dataset only and predict on the test dataset only. Thank you in advance!

Data is available here:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/teaching+assistant+evaluation
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/tae/

**Code:**

```
library("randomForest")
library(caTools)
# Importing tae.csv 
setwd("C:\\Users\\Saulat Majid\\Documents\\MSDataAnalytics\\DSU\\10 STAT 702 Modern Applied Statistics II - Saunders\\HW5")
tae <- read.table(file = "tae.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
head(tae)

colnames(tae) <- c("N_Speaker", "Instructor", "Course", "Summer", "C_Size", "Class")

# Numerical Summary of tae dataset
head(tae)
str(tae)
summary(tae)

# Converted categorical variables into factor
tae$Class <- as.factor(tae$Class)
tae$N_Speaker <- as.factor(tae$N_Speaker)
tae$Instructor <- as.factor(tae$Instructor)
tae$Summer <- as.factor(tae$Summer)
tae$Course <- as.factor(tae$Course)
str(tae)

# Splitting data into train and test
tae.Split <- sample.split(tae$Class, SplitRatio = 0.7)
table(tae.Split)
tae.train <- tae[tae.Split,]
tae.test  <- tae[!tae.Split,]
dim(tae)
dim(tae.train)
dim(tae.test)

rf <- randomForest(Class ~ N_Speaker + Summer + C_Size, data = tae, subset = tae.Split)
rf$predicted

predict(object = rf,
        newdata = tae[-tae.Split,],
        type = "response")
```

Comment: Why do you say that it is using the full data?  What do you get if you type `length(rf$predicted)` ?

Comment: I did try "length(rf$predicted)" and I got 105, which is correct. However, when I tried the following code, I got 150.my_predict <- predict(object = rf,
        newdata = tae[-tae.Split,],
        type = "response")
print(my_predict)
length(my_predict)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did try "length(rf$predicted)" and I got 105, which is correct. However, when I tried the measure the length of "predict()" function's output, I got 150 observations. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `tae[-tae.Split,]` is incorrect.  You need `tae[!tae.Split,]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, G5W. This worked!!!